# Specific error message vs generic?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Is it better to have specific error content in the error message?

```
var msg = util.format("current wallpaper %s isn't expected %s", current, expected)
```

Or to just have a generic error, a message that's the same for each case?

```
var msg = util.format("current wallpaper isn't expected")
```

I can see pros and cons for both.

Comment: When it comes to error messages my opinion is the more specific the better (easier) for the user to understand what the error message means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I would say that a more specific error message is better.  However, it partly depends on whether the error message is for developers or users.  If the error is for developers, then you definitely want to give as much information as possible to help correct the error.  If the error is for users, you may choose to keep it slightly more vague and say that "Something went wrong. Please try again later." or something along those lines.  Completely depends on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's better to throw in the variables into the `err` object?

```
var err = new Error("current wallpaper isn't expected")
err.background = background
err.expected = expected
```

Answer (score -1):

I also see pros and cons to both. I'm very, very new to programming, But between your two options, I would use the second one for clarity.

Edit: I was guessing that the program was for users and not developers.